# Company changed vacation policy to deny me 4 weeks, only a few days before I finally earned it

Tags: contracts, company-policy, vacation

In 2017 I had my 10 year anniversary on my job. I work for a small law firm. There are 5 full time lawyers and 1 part time lawyer. I am the only staff member.  When I began this job there were only 2 lawyers. I’ve stayed at this job because I know how long you have to be at a job to accrue 4 weeks vacation. As the firm grew, naturally my job has grown and to say I am busy is an understatement.

As per firm vacation policy, after 10 years I was entitled to 4 weeks vacation (1-4 years you get 2 weeks vacation and 5-9 years you get 3 weeks vacation). The policy had been in effect for 10 years.

So as of January 1, 2018 I would have earned earn 4 weeks vacation. However, I was told on December 20 that the firm was intending to change their vacation policy and nobody was allowed to take 4 weeks vacation.

I am the only employee (a different policy applies to because lawyers’ based on their billable hours). They said it’s because I am the only employee and they can’t have me gone for 4 weeks.  They acknowledged it didn’t look good on their part - being that they changed the policy just when it applied to me.

- Short of leaving the company as soon as I find another job, what are
  some other options in this situation?
- How might I approach re-negotiating the benefits and/or salary to make up for the change in vacation policy?
- Other than implying I can resign, is there anything else I can use as leverage in my negotiating position?

Comment: Is the beach house far? Can you still take three weeks now? And one week later in the year? It's in their interest to keep you happy.

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: @Dan- I am confused about whether to stay in my job, keep my 3 weeks vacation and try to work past the resentment I am feeling or just leave and start over somewhere else

Comment: Why "start over" somewhere else? Just negotiate for better pay and more vacation time in the new position.

Comment: (+1) The question is not very clear but it did attract valuable answers so I think it is worthwhile. Maybe worth reformulating a bit (shortening the context/explicitly asking about options)?

Comment: (@insidesin) Yes, strange. Especially the *start at the bottom of the vacation ladder* later in the question. As if the amount of vacation is the primary motivation for the job. Darianne, are you sure this is really your issue or do we have an [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: If I am understanding, the issue is taking 4 weeks off consecutively. But the OP is confusingly stating that she has 3 weeks of vacation so it's unclear exactly what the issue is. Are you trying to find a place that allows you to take the full 4 weeks off of vacation?

Comment: The amount of vacation time is sometimes negotiable when you get a new job. I got an extra week the last time I got hired because I would not agree to accept the job until they gave it to me. So at a minimum, don't accept less than the leave you currently get.

Comment: You work for lawyers, and you *WONDER* if they're unethical and conniving?  ... leaving that aside for a moment, if you are in a skilled role, your "position" on the vacation ladder is often negotiable at new companies, especially if you're willing to back down a touch on salary for it.

Comment: I will try to answer as many comments as possible. At this point, vacation time is very important.  My kids’ are recently out of college and now my husband and I are trying to focus on having some time to ourselves. So the vacation aspect is very important after years of not going anywhere but to take our kids to college.  Problem is they are not negotiating with the policy change at all. I feel duped.  I know the legal field. It will be very difficult for me to go to another firm and negotiate that kind of time off.  I guess I am partially venting and partially looking for  suggestions

Comment: @Darianne imagine if they changed the policy that you had to work 2 hours extra every day and your contract said differently? Would you take it? You have to cite resources that show they told you 4 weeks.

Comment: Can't you take unpaid vacation time? What would happen if you took a harder negotiating standpoint and told them it's four weeks of paid vacation or you'll be taking six weeks instead of four but you'll take two as unpaid. This gives you leverage beyond quitting which it sounds like they know you won't do.

Comment: How can they retroactively change the vacation policy? Isn't the policy part of your employment contract? If it's not, then what stops them from taking away _all_ your vacation if they feel like it?

Comment: `They said it’s because I am the only employee and they can’t have me gone for 4 weeks.` if they are saying that they can't have you gone for too long that means that you're in a sufficiently critical position that they wouldn't really be able to let you go easily. You may be able to use your poor bus factor and their dependency on you as your bargaining chip. Perhaps negotiate with them to hire a temp staff or train an existing employee to replace you whenever your away, in exchange of getting a four weeks vacation time. If they wouldn't budge, then you probably should find a new job.

Comment: Appalling ... I hope you quit & told them to go F themselves. That may in fact have been their goal - get you to quit so they can hire someone younger/cheaper who won't take any vacation time at all. Any enterprise that treats long-term employees with that level of callous disrespect doesn't deserve you. Is their nearest local competition hiring? Or willing to help you sue for breach of contract & age discrimination?

Answer (score 13):

While it is understandable that you feel betrayed by this behavior, be aware that it also tells you what is your better course of action: they cannot afford you to be away for 4 weeks? Find another job and be gone for more than 4 weeks! (and stitch to the minimum notice when giving the news to them)

You say you have several years experience, so you won't start from the bottom of the ladder when job searching.

It really doesn't matter if they have done this to force you to leave or because they really can't afford you to be gone: they admittedly changed the rules to prevent you from having benefit from them.

From their point of you view if you just swallow it without any reaction, it just set the threshold for how much you can be squeezed a tad further.

Comment: I should add they are labor lawyers. All we do is advise businesses how to handle HR issues and defend employment lawsuits.  They would NEVER advise a client to do this. All the other lawyers (non owners) privately apologized and said they were horrified by how I was treated

Comment: No I am not looking to take the 4 weeks off consecutively.  Just looking for the policy - that they wrote- to be applied to me now that I’ve earned it

Answer (score 8):

Both you and your employer have real problems to solve. You want more vacation, and were promised it until it was almost due. Your employer is worried about you being away for four weeks at a time. They handled it extremely badly, but remember they are not experienced HR people, but lawyers with one employee. There may have been an element of panic.

There should be a win-win in there somewhere, and you probably have the best skills and motivation for finding it.

How have your three week vacations been handled? Can that be extended to four weeks? Could bringing a temp worker on a week before your vacation for training help them look after things for the four weeks? Are there ways you could organize your work to make a four week vacation smooth?

Could you take two vacations each slightly longer than two weeks work? That way you get five weeks total vacation, but your longest absence would be shorter than the three weeks they have already handled.

Try to construct a plan that gets you vacation you will be happy with, and that ensures smooth operation while you are away. Write a report or presentation on it, and discuss it with whoever normally acts as your supervisor.

I see no problem with also testing the job market, and including your vacation time requirements in your salary and benefits negotiations.

Comment: *bringing a temp worker* It sounds more structural, i.e. they need extra staff.

Comment: @JanDoggen You may well be right. They have a poor [bus factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bus_factor) if they are so dependent on the OP being there. I am just suggesting the OP analyze the situation and make recommendations, not what those recommendations should be.

Comment: @ jan Doggen what’s an x-y problem?

Comment: @Darianne for an explanation, see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem